# Can't add foreign key to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

I have multiple tables and they all seem to be fine but there is this one table which I'm trying to create but it wont work because I am keep on getting `Error1005 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"`.

These are the two tables. I don't know what seems to be the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE Patient(             
ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
Age TINYINT UNSIGNED,
Sex VARCHAR(10),
Contact INT(11),
Email TEXT(2083), 
PRIMARY KEY(ID) 
);


CREATE TABLE Appointments (
Appointment_No INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Contact INT(11),
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Time TIME NOT NULL,
Reason TEXT(2083), 
PRIMARY KEY(Appointment_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Name, Contact) REFERENCES Patient (Name, Contact)

);
```

Comment: Please read about [Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Answer (score 0):

As per me, table structure should be like below:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient(             
ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
Age TINYINT UNSIGNED,
Sex VARCHAR(10),
Contact INT(11),
Email TEXT(2083), 
PRIMARY KEY(ID) 
);

CREATE TABLE Appointments (
Appointment_No INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Patient_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Time TIME NOT NULL,
Reason TEXT(2083), 
PRIMARY KEY(Appointment_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID) REFERENCES Patient (ID)

);
```

Comment: It works your way but is there a reason why your method works and my way doesn't ?

Comment: This would be the best solution, if it contained an explanation.

Comment: You can only foreign key reference to primary key column in parent table.  You can't reference to non primary key columns.

Comment: Understood thanks a lot. Would it be sensible if I make the contact and name UNIQUE?

Comment: @rsh your explanation is incorrect. See Bill's answer and my comments below it.

Comment: @Shadow  - you and Bill are correct you can reference to Primary key or Unique key columns in the parent table. Thanks

Comment: But ideally, name and contact columns are present in the parent table. its not required to repeat same information in child tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREIGN KEY (Name, Contact) REFERENCES Patient (Name, Contact)
```

The referenced columns in the Patient table must be part of a key. Ideally you would want Patient (Name, Contact) to be a unique key, because then the foreign key is guaranteed to reference exactly one row in the Patient table.

But in your table definition, the Name and Contact columns are not part of a key. That explains why you got the error given your table design.

But your table design is not good. Name and Contact are not good choices as a unique key, because two people can share a name, and in theory you could even have two people with the same name with the same contact details (for example, the former boxer George Foreman named his five sons George).

@Shadow is correct that it's a better idea is to reference `Patient(id)` instead, because it's guaranteed to be unique already.

Comment: Not just part of a key, but the first columns of an index in exactly the same order as specified in the foreign key.

Comment: And more to the point, the FK should reference the patient's id, not the name and contact fields.

Comment: Would it be a good idea if name and contact were unique as well?

Answer (score -1):

Try to split the two foreign keys in two lines like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Contact) REFERENCES Patient (Contact) 
FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFERENCES Patient (Name)
```

Answer (score -1):

Define Engine so sql statement would end with
ENGINE = MyISAM;

It should fix the issue.

Comment: myisam does not support foreign keys. period.

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE Appointments (
Appointment_No INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Contact INT(11),
Date DATE NOT NULL,
Time TIME NOT NULL,
Reason TEXT(2083), 
PRIMARY KEY(Appointment_No),
FOREIGN KEY (Name, Contact) REFERENCES Patient (Name, Contact)

) ENGINE = MyISAM;
'
I assume your default Engine is InnoDB which has certain constraints on foreign key http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Thanks it works now, but why does this method work and the normal way doesn't?

Comment: InnoDB has been the default storage engine since MySQL 5.5, circa 2010. If you don't specify the storage engine, you'll get InnoDB by default.